# TFS upgrade to update 4 do i need to upgrade build controllers?

Tags: tfs, upgrade

We are currently on **TFS** **2013** (Version 12.0.21005.1) and want to upgrade to **TFS**  **2013** **Update** **4** (Version 12.0.31101.0 TFS2013.Update4). 
Do we also need to upgrade our build and test controllers?

Our build and test controllers are Version 12.0.21005.1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your Build and Test controllers will still function if they're not upgraded. This means that you can first upgrade your TFS Server (Application tier and data tier) and then make sure everything still works.

After that you can upgrade your build and test controller one by one.